# Android app get forcely closed just after the splash scree - Appium C#

Tags: c#, appium

I have create a small test script to open a app and fill some data at the screen.
This test works fine with android 5 on Appium server 1.4.16.1

But no I need to run the same test script on a android 7 emulator and when I try to execute the test as soon as application get start ,It will get closed.

Below are my test scripts and Appium Log.
For android 7 im using appium V 1.13 server.

```
    public void AppiumSetupMethod()
    {

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.SetCapability("version", "4");
        capabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "emulator-5554");
        capabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.SetCapability("autoWebview", true);
        capabilities.SetCapability("resetKeyboard", true);
        capabilities.SetCapability("appPackage", "com.nike.snkrs");
        capabilities.SetCapability("appActivity", "feed.activities.TheWallActivity");
        capabilities.SetCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);
        capabilities.SetCapability("noReset", true);
        try
        {
            AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {


        }

        driver.Tap(1, 543, 762, 1000);
    }

 - [ADB] Running 'C:\Users\cja\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am start -W -n com.nike.snkrs/.feed.activities.TheWallActivity -S'
[AndroidDriver] Setting auto webview to context 'WEBVIEW_com.nike.snkrs' with timeout 2000ms
[AndroidDriver] Getting a list of available webviews
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\cja\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell cat /proc/net/unix'
[AndroidDriver] Found webviews: ["WEBVIEW_chrome"]
[AndroidDriver] Available contexts: ["NATIVE_APP","WEBVIEW_chrome"]
[AndroidDriver] Getting a list of available webviews
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\cja\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell cat /proc/net/unix'
[AndroidDriver] Found webviews: ["WEBVIEW_chrome"]
[AndroidDriver] Available contexts: ["NATIVE_APP","WEBVIEW_chrome"]
[AndroidDriver] Getting a list of available webviews
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\cja\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell cat /proc/net/unix'
[AndroidDriver] Found webviews: ["WEBVIEW_chrome"]
[AndroidDriver] Available contexts: ["NATIVE_APP","WEBVIEW_chrome"]
***[AndroidDriver] Getting a list of available webviews
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\cja\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell cat /proc/net/unix'
[AndroidDriver] Found webviews: ["WEBVIEW_chrome"]
[AndroidDriver] Available contexts: ["NATIVE_APP","WEBVIEW_chrome"]
[AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\cja\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop com.nike.snkrs'
[ADB] Pressing the HOME button
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\cja\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell input keyevent 3'***
[AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
[AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[UiAutomator] Shutting down UiAutomator
[UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopping'
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"OK, shutting down"}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Closed client connection
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] Time: 6.642
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] OK (1 test)
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
[UiAutomator] UiAutomator shut down normally
[UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'
[ADB] Attempting to kill all uiautomator processes
[ADB] Getting IDs of all 'uiautomator' processes
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\cja\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pgrep \^uiautomator\$'
[ADB] No 'uiautomator' process has been found
[UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'
[Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\cja\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop io.appium.unlock'
[AndroidDriver] Not cleaning generated files. Add `clearSystemFiles` capability if wanted.
[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1572086971859 (16:19:31 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time))
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: NoSuchContextError: No such context found.
[MJSONWP]     at AndroidDriver.setContext (C:\Program Files\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-android-driver\lib\commands\context.js:55:11)
[MJSONWP]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 9475 ms - 75
[HTTP]
```

So any idea on what need to be change on my test?